# Connection through router in iPad Mini

Tags: ios, ipad, wifi

I want to know whether I can get internet connection on my iPad Mini (WiFi only) through my router.
If yes, what are the criteria of that router?

Comment: I think any router will do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If it is a wireless router, iPad Mini allows you to connect to any standard wifi.

As per [Apple's technical specification page](http://www.apple.com/ipad-mini/specs/) the iPad Mini can connect to a network that meets the following requirements:

> 802.11a/b/g/n Wi‑Fi (802.11n 2.4GHz and 5GHz)

For example, if you have a 802.11 2.4GHz b network, the iPad Mini should connect to it.